# What do I do about links in locked posts that become malicious?

Tags: support, flags, locked-posts

There is [a post on Stack Overflow about Windows console applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60950/1438733) that has been locked due to historical significance.

However, one of the answers has a URL which previously linked to a Windows application website, but the domain has since been taken and registered by a malicious site.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987/1438733) from the question in... er, question, contains a link labelled "Poderosa". **Warning: Highly recommend NOT clicking the link within the answer.**

**I am unable to flag the answer**, the question, etc., but this link should definitely be removed by a moderator.

Why can't locked content be flagged? And can this link be dealt with?

Comment: Locked questions can't be flagged because in other cases flags kept coming in despite mod notices and comments to not flag the post. I admit that for the type of situation you encountered  all you have left is posting on meta...

Comment: @rene Yeah, that does make sense, though I think if you did something like limiting it by reputation (maybe 5k+? 10k?), and limiting the reasons for flagging, it would be much more manageable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good catch, I've removed the link.

In future cases, it'd work to flag one of your posts or one of the author's posts with an 'other' flag explaining what's going on.

Comment: That's a good enough alternative for me. Thanks!

Comment: sorry to bother but the project is still alive on `http://poderosa.sourceforge.net/`. I have edited the other posts that had the corrupt link and replaced it with the one for the sourceforge project. I leave it for you if you want to edit or not.