# Under what specific circumstances will historically locked content be updated?

Tags: support, historical-lock

This came up [in a recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356318/1079354) in which content from a historically locked question was updated.

As I understand historic locks, they're meant for content which was on-topic at one point in our site's history, but really aren't suitable for the site *now*, but they still hold *some* value to the site.  (While this raises other discussions of why bother with them at all, that's orthogonal to this discussion.)

It was the case that a decision was made to update content for that question.  While I still disagree with that decision, I'd like to be sure that my thinking on this process as a whole is right in spite of that.

**Under what specific criteria is a historically locked question deemed valuable enough to warrant updates from diamond moderators?**  Is view count alone enough (e.g. is there a specific view count that would give credence to updating it), or does there have to be something more for it to exist?  I'd like to understand the rationale so that I have a better grounding of situations like that, in spite of how rare they are.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The criteria are as follows:

- You ask nicely, using appropriate means, and clearly specify what you want to have happen;
- The diamond moderator who sees your request is willing to oblige you.

In other words, there *isn't* a policy or any specific criteria. Requests for a diamond moderator to do something are generally at the discretion of that diamond moderator.

I feel pretty strongly that there doesn't *need* to be a policy here, and the only policy that needs to exist is the one I set out in [my answer to that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356320), namely that one should not try and make a regular habit of this, and should consider any request that *does* get granted as a one-off favor.

[You said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356318/can-i-update-defunct-urls-on-a-post-that-is-locked-with-historical-significance#comment512873_356319):

> The rule doesn't have to be arbitrary. I'm okay with "at the moderator's discretion", but again since it's so rare I don't think it's ever come up. All I'm looking for is clarity.

…and that is rather the point. It is so rare that it hardly ever comes up, so we don't need a policy surrounding it (although [it's not totally unprecedented, either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342421/what-do-i-do-about-links-in-locked-posts-that-become-malicious/342423#342423)). Moderator discretion is more than sufficient. We're trusted to use discretion on issues much more complicated and significant than this.

Personally, I believe overly dogmatic approaches are almost always counter-productive, and that seems very much to be the approach that you've taken here. As I said before, if you want to campaign for the deletion of a historically-locked question, then you are well within your rights to do so. But arguing that a moderator *shouldn't* make an edit that, by all objective standards, *improves* the quality of the post, when asked to do so by the owner of that post, doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I believe your answer is spot on, and I've +1ed it. However, your frustration bleeds through in your choice of words. That often happens to me, so I completely understand. But as a moderator, you may wish to work on writing in a way that tones your feelings on an issue down. I know if I am on the receiving end of wording like your last paragraph, it's difficult for me to not get more frustrated and upset; in other words, it risks escalating the situation instead of defusing it. Just something to consider. Maybe speak with other mods about their opinion on it.

Comment: @jpmc26 What? Cody is like the next best thing there is to moderation after unplugging a computer. Joking aside, feeling feelings from moderators is totally not something I frown upon. Actually it feels... pretty damn good to have a moderator speak up in ways I can totally, as a pretty sanguine person myself, identify with. And here I am assuming your point is valid at all.