# Why does this question include the answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

I was looking at [What does Ruby have that Python doesn't, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113611/what-does-ruby-have-that-python-doesnt-and-vice-versa?rq=1) and it seems to me that the question shouldn't include the answer, whether it's a Wiki or not. I'm surprised that is hasn't been edited given how many views/upvotes it has.

Have I misunderstood best practices on SO somehow?

Comment: It can't be edited because it is locked

Comment: According to the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1113611/revisions?page=2), the question was problematic from the get go, so the asker converted it to community wiki and started adding answers to the question, most likely as a misunderstanding of what community wiki is all about.

Comment: Back in July 2009 they did not yet know what constructive questions should look like.  Took a fat year to figure out through trial and error.  Didn't otherwise stop Google from bringing a hundred thousand visitors to the question and  0.2% of them voting it helpful.  Hard to get rid of, deleting it would break the Internet and tick-off lots of "why you change the rules" contributors.  So locking it is about all that can be done with it.

Comment: @HansPassant Unlocking just to cut out the answer part and post as a separate answer, and locking again seems reasonable to me. Especially if it's so popular, it can confuse visitors on how SO question should look like.

Comment: @BartoszKP You have the makings of a good Meta question here, along the lines of, "Should we unlock/edit/relock questions of this sort?"

Comment: @KellyS.French This one seems close enough: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356370/under-what-specific-circumstances-will-historically-locked-content-be-updated :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The post is [*locked for historical significance*.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) It can't be edited, at all. It is frozen in time.

It is also not listed on the site outside of user accounts; generally only external search engines or web pages would let you find it, or by knowing what users participated on the page, then looking through their post lists.

The question was created during the formative period of Stack Overflow, when the community was still trying to figure out what kinds of questions worked, and what would not. That post was one that did not work. Only its high search-engine ranking saves it from outright deletion.

As the note on the page states:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

Since it can't be edited, you shouldn't expect it to be fixed to follow current best practices either.

Comment: _It is also not listed on the site outside of user accounts; generally only external search engines or web pages would let you find it, or by knowing what users participated on the page, then looking through their post lists._  **Is this behavior applies for all locked questions?**

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: no, only historical locks have this effect, and only on non-meta sites.